# Tensor equations. Can I change an equation from covariant to contravariant?

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

Say I have a tensor equation like $G_{ab}=R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R$. Does this also imply that $G^{ab}=R^{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g^{ab}R$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you want to do it explicitly, just multiply both sides with the inverse metric to raise both indices.

Comment: Yea that is what I thought as well thank you for confirming.

Comment: I'm still learning index manipulation. Any chance of checking that my answer to this question is correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is the correct, full calculation.
$$G_{ab}=R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R.$$
First, multiply by $g^{ac}$
$$g^{ac}G_{ab}=g^{ac}R_{ab}-g^{ac}\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R$$
$$G_{b}^{c}=R_{b}^{c}-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{b}^{c}R.$$
Then multiply by $g^{ab}$
$$g^{ab}G_{b}^{c}=g^{ab}R_{b}^{c}-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{b}^{c}g^{ab}R.$$
$$G^{ac}=R^{ac}-\frac{1}{2}g^{ac}R.$$
Relabel $c$ as $b$
$$G^{ab}=R^{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g^{ab}R.$$
Two days later - someone has kindly confirmed this is OK, here: [Raising and lowering indices - any chance of checking my work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456777/raising-and-lowering-indices-any-chance-of-checking-my-work)