# Raising and lowering indices - any chance of checking my work?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, tensors

I'm trying to teach myself some basic differential geometry in relation to general relativity. Would anyone be willing to check my work showing the steps involved in multiplying

$$G_{ab}=R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R$$
 by the inverse metric to get $$G^{ab}=R^{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g^{ab}R.$$

First, multiply by $g^{ac}$
 $$g^{ac}G_{ab}=g^{ac}R_{ab}-g^{ac}\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R$$

$$G_{b}^{c}=R_{b}^{c}-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{b}^{c}R.$$

Then multiply by $g^{ab}$

$$g^{ab}G_{b}^{c}=g^{ab}R_{b}^{c}-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{b}^{c}g^{ab}R.$$

$$G^{ac}=R^{ac}-\frac{1}{2}g^{ac}R.$$

Relabel $c$
  as $b$
 $$G^{ab}=R^{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g^{ab}R.$$

I did originally post this answer here, [Tensor equations. Can I change an equation from covariant to contravariant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203573/tensor-equations-can-i-change-an-equation-from-covariant-to-contravariant/1455289#1455289), but didn't get a response. Thanks

Comment: This looks fine. The only thing I would add is when you say "multiply by $g^{ac}$," it would be more accurate to say "multiply by $g^{ac}$ and sum over $a$," and similarly when you multiply by $g^{ab}$. This is because each of your equations that has a repeated index in each term actually has an implied summation.

Comment: @JackLee - Thanks very much. I know it's really basic stuff, but when you're teaching yourself it's hard to find step by step derivations that are pitched at the beginner's level.